# Why PHP authentication works incorrect?

Tags: php, authentication, pdo, password-hash

I am newbie in PHP. 
I have simple authentication script. It works incorrect: user "test" (100% existing in table in DB) can not pass auth (error text - "User is not found!").

Use PHP7, MySQL, connection method is PDO.

Need some help please.

```
$data = $_POST;
// check if button is pressed
if (isset($data['enter-auth'])) {

  // check fileds
  $errors = array();
  if (trim($data['login_auth']) == '' ) {
    $errors[] = 'Enter login';
  }
    if (($data['password_auth']) == '' ) {
    $errors[] = 'Enter password';
  }

// If all fields are filled, save user's data in vars
$login = $data['login_auth'];
$password = password_hash($data['password_auth'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

// ... and look in table
try {
    if (empty($errors)) {

      // Check if login and password exists in table
      $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE login=? AND password=?");
      $stmt->execute([$login, $password]);
      $count = $stmt->fetchColumn();

      // If login and pwd found in table counter will be > 0, so ...
      if ($count > 0) {

      // ... then we can check if password is correct
          if (password_verify($data['password_auth'], $password)) {

           // if entered and stored passwords match, user is welcome
           $_SESSION['auth_name'] = $data['login_auth'];

           echo '<div style="color: green;">Welcome, '.$_SESSION['auth_name'].';
           echo '<a href="/a/logout.php">Exit</a>';
           header('Location: /a/index.php');

          } else {
            $errors[] = 'Password is incorrect';
            echo '<p id="message">Wrong password!</p>';  
          }


      } else {
          $errors[] = 'User not found';
          echo '<p id="message">User is not found!</p>'; 
      }

   } else {
    echo '<div style="color: red;">'.array_shift($errors).'</div>';
   }

 } catch(PDOException $e) {
     echo $e->getMessage();
 }

// close condition check if button is pressed
}
```

Notes:

I tryed debugging this script using var_dump.

If I use fetchAll() when searching in table, any entered ldin is accepted (even if there is no such user).

Used try/catch construction with debug aim, I've heard that in production it is deprecated because of security reason.

Comment: you have parse errors

Comment: You're using `password_hash()` incorrectly. This function generates a new hash that is almost 100% guaranteed to be different from any other hashes it has generated before for the same password. So you will not find the user in your database by checking if the hash matches.

Comment: @Funk Forty Niner, checked with                        
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);                                                                              and run script from console but don't see any parse errors except "headers already sent..." error, but I think it doesn't affect in my problem...                                                                                                    Could you suggest right way of finding the parse errors? Thanks.

Comment: you can Google that error and look here on Stack; there are reasons for that output.

Comment: @Funk Forty Niner, I already worked the well-known "headers already sent.." error, googled it last month. In this script I solve it by earsing "session start()" in the auth script and using only in dbconnect.php file which is required in all my files. So now there is 0 errors I see using ini_set and console command #php script.php...

Comment: @rickdenhaan, yes, but I use password_verify() function, which verifies that the given hash matches the given password according to manual
http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php
If I am wrong in this, could you tell me please right method of verifying password entered by user (clear text) with stored in DB hashed password? Thank you.

Comment: @aysee You need to use `password_verify()` to compare `$data['password_auth']` with the hash stored in your database. With your current query, you're not retrieving the hash from your database.

Comment: @rickdenhaan, thank you. Your comment was not entirely specific about query, but it brought me to mind about password_verify() syntax, so I;ve stydied tutorials describing it, and finally discovered true answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found mistakes, rewrote the code according to https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/password_hash
So, correct fragment is:

```
try {

 if (empty($errors)) {
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT login, password FROM users WHERE login=?");
  $stmt->execute([$login]);
  $user = $stmt->fetch();

      if ($user && password_verify($data['password_auth'], $user['password'])) {

       $_SESSION['auth_name'] = $data['login_auth'];
       echo '<div style="color: green;">Welcome, '.$_SESSION['auth_name'].';
       echo '<a href="/a/logout.php">Exit</a>';
       header('Location: /a/index.php');

      } else {
        $errors[] = 'Login or password error';
        echo '<p id="message-auth">Login or password is incorrect!</p>';  
      }

  } else {
    echo '<div style="color: red;">'.array_shift($errors).'</div>';
  }

} catch(PDOException $e) {
       echo $e->getMessage();
}
```